# When is the onSignInSucceeded() method called in an Android game?

Tags: android, authentication, google-play-games

I am trying to implement a Google Play Games service login function. I am using this as a guide: https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin

I have an Activity which inherits from BaseGameActivity, thus the login is initiated when the app starts. This works perfectly. However I want to know when it is exactly performed. I.e does it occur after onCreate() or onStart() are called?

If I were to add game_helper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0); in onCreate(), will it always stop all attempts to login even before they begin? Or will the login sequence be stopped after it has started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup is done in `onCreate()` and sign-in is performed in `onStart()`.

The best way to prevent sign-in on start completely is to set `game_helper.mConnectOnStart = false;` in your activities' `onCreate()`.

The following is the code that is called in `onStart` (part of GameHelper.java):

```
public void onStart(Activity act) {
    mActivity = act;
    mAppContext = act.getApplicationContext();

    debugLog("onStart");
    assertConfigured("onStart");

    if (mConnectOnStart) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.w(TAG,
                    "GameHelper: client was already connected on onStart()");
        } else {
            debugLog("Connecting client.");
            mConnecting = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        debugLog("Not attempting to connect becase mConnectOnStart=false");
        debugLog("Instead, reporting a sign-in failure.");
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyListener(false);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```